# How to use an array to set multiple selection critieria in one line in java?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

To be more accurate, is it possible to make something like this:

```
  String[]  varIn={"1",
                   "2",
                   "3"};
  in=input.nextLine();
  if(in.equalsIgnoreCase(varIn[0]) || 
     in.equalsIgnoreCase(varIn[1]) || 
     in.equalsIgnoreCase(varIn[2]))
                  System.out.println(" it works! ");
```

into something like this:

```
  String[]  varIn={"1",
                   "2",
                   "3"};
 in=input.nextLine();
 if(in.equalsIgnoreCase(varIn[])) // << varIn[]'s place should contain all 
                                  //    the strings in varIn[]
                  System.out.println(" it works! ");
```

where if(in.equalsIgnoreCase(varIn[])) will contain all the strings to compare for all the strings in the array. I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this, but i don't see how. Any chance any one has an alternative or solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Edit:removed typos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a for loop, or with `Stream` pipeline (if you can use Java 8):

```
if (Stream.of(varIn).anyMatch(s->in.equalsIgnoreCase(s)))
```

or

```
if (Stream.of(varIn).anyMatch(in::equalsIgnoreCase))
```

This is assuming there is only one `in` variable you wish to compare against the elements of the array (it appears your `in[1]` and `in[2]` may have been a typo).

Comment: Also mention that this is java 8

Comment: Plus you don't need an intermediate `varIn` array if created only for this check. `Stream.of("1", "2", "3")` would also do in that case.

Comment: @MarkusBenko That's true, but we don't know if it was created only for this check.

Comment: @Eran That's also true, but knowing that there are overloaded variants of `Stream.of()` when being new to Java 8 and/or Stream API also wouldn't harm.

Answer (score 0):

In pre Java 8:

```
Set<String> varIn = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
in = readLine();
if(in != null && varIn.contains(in.toLowerCase())) ... //maybe, toUpperCase
```

Comment: By using `new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` instead and then adding the three elements you would have a set that you can use with `contains(in)` directly without any case conversion.